# Пересобрать массив цикле

Tags: php, json

есть такой json:

[{
   "price":"1",
   "params":"remove.png",
   "name":"product1",
   "count": 1
},
{
   "price":"2",
   "params":"remove.png",
   "name":"product2",
   "count": 5
}]

Нужно его пересобрать в таком виде (повторяем товар count раз и убираем count и элемента json):

```
[
{
   "price":"1",
   "params":"remove.png",
   "name":"product1",
},
{
   "price":"1",
   "params":"remove.png",
   "name":"product1",
},
{
   "price":"2",
   "params":"remove.png",
   "name":"product2",
},
{
   "price":"2",
   "params":"remove.png",
   "name":"product2",
}
]
```

Как это лучше сделать?

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно воспользоваться [array_fill](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-fill.php), чтобы создать повторяющиеся массивы

```
$arr = json_decode($str, true);

$res = [];
foreach($arr as $x) {
    $count = $x['count'];
    unset($x['count']);
    $res = array_merge($res, array_fill(0, $count, $x));
}
echo json_encode($res);

[
  {"price":"1","params":"remove.png","name":"product1"},
  {"price":"2","params":"remove.png","name":"product2"},
  {"price":"2","params":"remove.png","name":"product2"},
  {"price":"2","params":"remove.png","name":"product2"},
  {"price":"2","params":"remove.png","name":"product2"},
  {"price":"2","params":"remove.png","name":"product2"}
]
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо!